# npm not pulling down code from latest version

Tags: typescript, npm, nestjs

I've created this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-notifications

I'm released v0.0.9 using `np` having made a few changes. I'm now trying to pull these into my other projects, but whilst npm is saying it has installed v0.0.9, it is not pulling down changes since v0.0.7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only thing I can guess is that on publish, a new `dist` wasn't built so the old dist is what was published. Can you check the `dist` of the installed package, check the `package.json` version, and make sure you see what you expect, or if you see the old code?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply - running npm build on my computer builds the package as expected. The dist that appears when importing from other apps does not show the same dist. Instead, the old one, circa v0.0.7.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the lockfile isn't updated and so it's being resolved to an older version

Comment: Hi Jay - this still isn't working. I've deleted the package-lock a few times now and it's not pulling down the latest code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Trying it myself installs the latest version of your package (0.1.11). I don't know what to say honestly